# my code comes up with a System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParseException error

Tags: c#

I have written a program that attempts to removes all of the consonants from the given stringusing the string with consonants removed, finds the longest sequence of the same vowel and outputs the length of that sequence.

I tried to use Regex to solve this problem.

Here is the code I  updated so far:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


RemoveConsonantsAndFindLongestVowelSequence("musicisthebestbeatofall");

static void RemoveConsonantsAndFindLongestVowelSequence(string input)
{
    // Define the consonants
    string consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

    // Remove all consonants from the string
    StringBuilder noConsonants = new StringBuilder();
    string lastVowel = "";
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (!consonants.Contains(c))
        {
            noConsonants.Append(c);
            if ("AEIOUaeiou".Contains(c))
            {
                if (lastVowel == "")
                {
                    lastVowel = c.ToString();
                }
                else if (c == lastVowel[0])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    lastVowel = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Find the longest sequence of the same vowel
    MatchCollection vowelSequences = Regex.Matches(noConsonants.ToString(), lastVowel + "+");
    string longestSequence = "";
    foreach (Match m in vowelSequences)
    {
        if (m.Value.Length > longestSequence.Length)
        {
            longestSequence = m.Value;
        }
    }

    // Output the length of the longest sequence
    Console.WriteLine(longestSequence.Length);
}
```

#### The problem I am facing

The output for the first two and the last is  correct but for the third one is incorrect as shown below:

```
Argument                             : Expected           : Actual
----------------------------------------------------------------------
iii                                  : 3                  : 3 
xoxoxoxox                            : 4                  : 4
musicisthebestbeatofall              : 3                  : error
dontworrybehoppynow                  : 2                  : error
```

I checked the Watch window in the debugger, and it shows as null for lastVowel.

Comment: How is your code trying to isolate sequences *of the same vowel*?  Your first 2 cases are correct b/c there is only 1 vowel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [backreferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences), the first parenthesis matches one character, `\1*` matches the remaining identical characters.

```
// Remove all consonants from the string
string noConsonants = new string(input.Where(c => !consonants.Contains(c)).ToArray());

// Find all sequences of vowels in the string
MatchCollection vowelSequences = Regex.Matches(noConsonants, "([aeiouAEIOU])\\1*");
```

Note: We write `"...\\"` to escape the `\` character. It could also be written `@"....\1*"`

Additionally, if you only need to know the length, subsequent linq expressions can also be simplified.

```
// Find the longest sequence of the same vowel
int longest = vowelSequences.Max(m => m.Value.Length);

// Output the length of the longest sequence
Console.WriteLine(longest);
```

Comment: I have edited your answer, maybe I overdid it. Feel free to rollback it if it deviates from your intent.